# Resizing a JFrame and maintain aspect ratio?

Tags: java, swing, resize

I want the user to resize the window while maintaining the same aspect ratio (rectangle in which the width > height. In other words, if height is changed, I want to force width to change by a larger amount, and vice versa.  Preferably, I want the resize to happen while the window is being resized, not after. The code below isn't working for me at all.. and whenever I try to resize the window it just reverts back to its original size. Even when I drag to resize, it doesn't change both width AND height. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0)
{
    int setHeight = arg0.getComponent().getHeight();
    int setWidth = arg0.getComponent().getWidth();
    double newWidth = 0;
    double newHeight = 0;
    {
        if(setHeight != oldHeight)
        {
            heightChanged = true;
        }
        if(setWidth != oldWidth)
        {
            widthChanged = true;
        }
    }
    {
        if(widthChanged == true && heightChanged == false)
        {
            newWidth = setWidth;
            newHeight = setWidth*HEIGHT_RATIO;
        }
        else if(widthChanged == false && heightChanged == true)
        {
            newWidth = setHeight * WIDTH_RATIO;
            newHeight = setHeight;
        }
        else if(widthChanged == true && heightChanged == true)
        {
            newWidth = setWidth;
            newHeight = setWidth*HEIGHT_RATIO;
        }
    }

    int x1 = (int) newWidth;
    int y1 = (int) newHeight;
    System.out.println("W: " + x1 + " H: " + y1);
    Rectangle r = arg0.getComponent().getBounds();
    arg0.getComponent().setBounds(r.x, r.y, x1, y1);
    widthChanged = false;
    heightChanged = false;
    oldWidth = x1;
    oldHeight = y1;
}
```

Comment: The component is probably under the control of a layout manager...

Comment: If you could provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduce the problem, it would be easier to find a solution.

Comment: A simple solution might be to write a layout manage whose sole responsibility is to resize the child component based on a supplied ratio so that the child component will always fit within the parent container but will maintain the aspect ratio correctly

Answer (score 4):

There is no easy way to achieve that using Java (AWT limitiation).

Possible solutions:

- correct window size after the user stopped resizing (annoying from the users pov)
- use a unresizable JWindow/JDialog without any decorations and re-implement window resizing programmatically. Cursor shapes etc. is avaiable with Swing/AWT. I have done this in a commercial project (so no source :-) ). Only problem with that: it is quite volatile regarding platforms/jdk versions (though AWT/Swing is not changed that much in recent years).

manipulating the window size while user is dragging/resizing will not work properly

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to keep a JPanel's aspect ratio as a square for a school project. It took a few different elements in different places, so I hope I can give enough information to help you implement the method into your own project using whatever aspect ratio you want. I was able to boil it down to two java files. Not sure how to condense it any further

the first: AspectRatio.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class AspectRatio {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stay a square");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new SquarePanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

the second has the meat of it: SquarePanel.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SquarePanel extends JPanel {
    //Fields
    private JPanel square;
    private int panelHeight;
    private int panelWidth;
    //Constructor
    public SquarePanel() {
        square = new JPanel();
        square.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        square.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,800));
        this.addComponentListener(new FrameSizeListener());
        this.add(square);
    }
    //resizing method
    public void resizeSquare() {
        panelHeight = super.getHeight();
        panelWidth = super.getWidth();
        if(panelHeight>(panelWidth)) {
            square.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(panelWidth,panelWidth));
        }
        else if (panelHeight<(panelWidth)) {
            square.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(panelHeight,panelHeight));
        }
    }
    //Window resizing listener
    private class FrameSizeListener implements ComponentListener{
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            resizeSquare();
            revalidate();
        }
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
        }
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
        }
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps. The code as is will just make a black square on a white background, but the square stays a square and stays as big as it can.